# Eclipse 4 RCP with ibm rational Doors Database

Tags: eclipse-plugin, database-connection, eclipse-rcp, e4, ibm-doors

I am creating Eclipse RCP application and i am using doors database so please help me how to integrate with eclipse RCP? Any JAR? How to database connection with java and doors?

Comment: Could you share what you tried ?? and wherer you are stucked.

Comment: Hi Sir, Sir i am creating Eclipse 4 RCP applicatin and my backend database is IBM DOORs but i don't have idea how to integrate with RCP ?any JAR required or not ?